# Fiware Iot agent UL & mqtts protocol

Tags: fiware

I am using the IoT Agent for Ultralight.
I am sending my data via mqtt. My broker uses the mqtts protocol. It works with the json iot agent but not with UL. Apparently I can't set a protocol type like in the json agent. My colleagues stick to the UL agent. So I'd like to use that as well. 
Does anyone know the right way to connect to a tls mqtt-broker with the UL agent? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The latest is [1.13.0 Release](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/releases/tag/1.13.0) includes a port the MQTT over SSL support from the JSON IoT Agent over to the Ultralight IoT Agent.

The important changes for secure MQTT support can be found [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/240d5f9fd6064645fdb98793f93b0778397b745b/lib/bindings/MQTTBinding.js#L228-#L300) - the most relevant part is summarized below:

```js
var options = {
        protocol:  'mqtt',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 1883,
        key: fs.readFileSync(mqttConfig.key, 'utf8') : null,
        ca: fs.readFileSync(mqttConfig.ca, 'utf8') : null,
        cert: fs.readFileSync(mqttConfig.cert, 'utf8') : null,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        keepalive: 0,
        connectTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000
    };

var mqttClient = mqtt.connect(
        options.protocol + '://' + mqttConfig.host + ':' + mqttConfig.port,
        options
    );
```

This is merely stuffing the `options` available within the standard Node.JS [MQTT Client](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/#client)

Since this PR has been merged,it is now possible to use the `latest` docker image and supply Docker variables to add username, password, ca authority and so on.

The following new Docker `ENV` variables are defined:

```
| Environment variable          | Configuration attribute |
| ----------------------------  |  ---------------------- |
| IOTA_MQTT_PROTOCOL            | mqtt.protocol           |
| IOTA_MQTT_CA                  | mqtt.ca                 |
| IOTA_MQTT_CERT                | mqtt.cert               |
| IOTA_MQTT_KEY                 | mqtt.key                |
| IOTA_MQTT_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED | mqtt.rejectUnauthorized |
| IOTA_MQTT_USERNAME            | mqtt.username           |
| IOTA_MQTT_PASSWORD            | mqtt.password           |
```

`IOTA_MQTT_KEY`, `IOTA_MQTT_USERNAME` and `IOTA_MQTT_PASSWORD` can be hidden as [Docker secrets](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/tree/master/docker#docker-secrets) and alias in the usual manner by adding the `_FILE` suffix.